# Meaning of いざ出陣?

Tags: translation, nuances

I'm reading a book titled ダンジョンに出会いを求めるのは間違っているだろうか, and I came across this sentence:

> ギルドに名前を登録していざ出陣。

on the first page. I'm having trouble understanding the `いざ出陣`. I have a feeling that it's implying something like "register your name in the guild and get ready for battle". When I searched 出陣 on jisho.org it kind of threw me off on my original meaning.

If this wasn't from an anime novel, what would be the most common way to say what they wanted? Would it be something like `軍隊が出る`?

Answer (score 3):

From a comment by [ericabeno](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/29347/ericfromabeno):

> 戦い・試合に出ること to head out for battle, deploy

Japanese definition from [大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/105841/meaning/m0u/).